# Different behavior for pseudo-class with space and without space

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

This issue is related to CSS pseudo-class. I refer to :last-child just for example, I suppose it happens to all other pseudo-class too.

1. Given I have following simple HTML:

```html
<body>
    <p>Paragraph1</p>
    <p>Paragraph2</p>
</body>
```

2. I add following CSS:

```css
body:last-child{
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <p>Paragraph1</p>
 <p>Paragraph2</p>
</body>
```

*Without space both paragraphs will be marked as red*

3. When I will set space between .body and :last-child, only second paragraph will be marked as red - that happens in Google Chrome, I see snippet tool doesn't mark any paragraph with red.

```css
body: last-child{
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <p>Paragraph1</p>
 <p>Paragraph2</p>
</body>
```

**Question:** Could anyone help me understand why this happens? Maybe anything to read more on behaviour with space and without space for pseudo-class?

Answer (score 2):

It's last paragraph not last body.

So, just do this:

```
body p:last-child{
   color: red;
}
```

Space separates the next level of elements for css selector to work.

Answer (score 0):

With `body:last-child`, you target the last **body** (and there is only one). So everything within the body will be colored red.

The `body: last-child` doesn't work, because it is invalid.

What you are looking for is `body p:last-child`.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Without spacing**

```css
body:last-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Paragraph1</p>
  <p>Paragraph2</p>
</body>
```

In the above code, all the `p` elements are red because `color: red` is applied to the body and is applied to the child elements as well. `body:last-child`, here `:last-child` is w.r.t to the parent and does not mean last child of body element.

---

**2. With spacing**

```
body: last-child{
  color:red;
}
```

The above is invalid syntax and does not apply styling. You can validate your CSS: [**W3C CSS Validator**](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator)

---

**3. Solution:**

```
body p:last-child { /* Select the paragraph which is last inside body */
  color: red;
}
```

Avoid using this in SO snippets as the child selectors will be difficult to style. `<link>` and `<script>` is added/appended to the markup and disrupts the child selector.

Answer (score 0):

pseudo-element should always work without Space in between of element and colon .eg

body p:last-child{ color:red; }